# Delete every entity that was spawned | Python ursina

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-engine, ursina

How do I delete every Entity that was spawned?

For example:

```
Entity1 = Entity(...)
Entity2 = Entity(...)
Entity3 = Entity(...)

destroy(scene.entities) # Just an example
```

How do I delete all those with one or multiple lines of code without appending to a list?

Trying to delete every entity that was intialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
scene.clear()
```

or

```py
[destroy(e) for e in scene.entities]
```

Using a list comprehension can be easier than using a for loop, since it won't mess up the list while you're iterating.